# Is there a searchable index for WotC images published in Dragon/Dungeon magazine?

Tags: art, wizards-of-the-coast

Is there a master index of all the images available in the Wizards of the Coast Art Gallery files?  When I want to find a specific image, I have to open the file for each individual issue of Dragon/Dungeon magazine.  The WotC search tool doesn't appear to index the images in the Art Gallery files.  Neither does Google because the files are behind the DDI paywall.  I would like to just search an index that tells me what Dungeon/Dragon issue contains the image and then I can just open the one file from the Art Gallery Archive for that issue. Am I'm missing something?

Comment: Great question!

Comment: I'm really intrigued to see if anyone can find (or create) a resource like @ChrisP describes.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would want to search for an image?

Comment: @GMNoob I'd like to see something keyword driven. Even as simple as a brief picture description (*red dragon*, *ruins*). Ideally you could search by even more descriptive phrases (*elder red dragon breathing fire*, *dark gloomy ruins*).

Comment: I can't compare, as I don't know if this has everything, but it gives you a lot of hits.... Enter "site:http://www.wizards.com/dnd/ red dragon" into the image search bar in google Images.  http://www.google.com/search?um=1&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&biw=1333&bih=790&tbm=isch&oq=site:http://www.wizards.com/dnd/++red++dragon&aq=f&aqi=&q=site:http://www.wizards.com/dnd/%20red%20dragon

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is no public tool or list that has this information. Now if someone has a passion for this and nearly infinite time then they could start one...

You might try sending a customer service email to WotC and see if they have something. This may be your best bet.

Comment: With the move from minatures to tokens, it would be very useful to find a specific image for making home made tokens with photoshop.

Comment: Absolutely. You have given me an idea to think on.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of.  WotC release packs of their images from each new book to subscribers, and that would make a good starting point.

Start tagging those images. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for as 4th edition is before my time but by doing [a Web Google search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search?q=site:archive.wizards.com) on the domain archive.wizards.com you might be able to get some results as it looks like all the images are up on [the site](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/arch/ag&page=2) and the pages themselves were not marked no-index (only the images).

There's also the DM's Guild [which has art assets for people making content for the DM's Guild](http://www.dmsguild.com/browse/pub/8957/Dungeon-Masters-Guild?filters=0_0_45476_0_0_0). I don't know what you're trying to do with the art, but you might be able to use them if you're not going to distribute it outside of the DM's Guild.